# Replace with New line in place of pipe symbol in python using re module

Tags: python, regex

I have following code, which extracts text between the **BusContact** tag. But I want to print the text in two lines. In summary, replace '|' symbol with '\n'. I have used re module.

```
searchstring = '<BusContact>kdsfdfskfsdffsdsdf|sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf</BusContact>'
import re
contactdetail = re.compile('<BusContact>(.*?)</BusContact>').search(searchstring)
buscontactdetail = contactdetail.group(1)
print(buscontactdetail)
```

**Current output:**
kdsfdfskfsdffsdsdf|sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf

**Expected Output:**

kdsfdfskfsdffsdsdf

sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf

Comment: So, split `group(1)` with `|`, `contactdetail.group(1).split('|')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just have to use replace:

```
searchstring = '<BusContact>kdsfdfskfsdffsdsdf|sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf</BusContact>'
import re
contactdetail = re.compile('<BusContact>(.*?)</BusContact>').search(searchstring)
buscontactdetail = contactdetail.group(1)
buscontactdetail = buscontactdetail.replace('|','\n')
print(buscontactdetail)
```

output:

```
kdsfdfskfsdffsdsdf
sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
```